# Can't understand some definitions of abstract algebra, can you help me please?

Tags: abstract-algebra, definition

I was reading different definitions of vector space but still I have some dark places without meaning... I can't understand exactly what type of relation is defined between the vector space and the field **over** which is defined...

I can't understand what exactly is the meaning of **over**. A example that I take from Wikipedia:

> *A vector space **over** a field $F$ is a set $V$ together with two operations that satisfy the >eight axioms listed below. Elements of $V$ are called vectors. Elements of $F$ are called >scalars. In this article, vectors are distinguished from scalars by boldface.*

I can't understand the relation between scalar of field $K$ and the $n$-tuple of any $V$ vector space. Where is the relation on dimensions, tuples and scalars? Of course the tuples are expressed in terms of $K$ but the expression **over** is a bit confusing.

More obscure is to call to the scalar multiplication as a "external" operation where the space vector is defined **over** $K$, how it can be "external" if the vector space itself is defined over $K$? External over itself?

These types of definitions seem to me just justified by practical uses (for physics or so) but lack A LOT of real deepness in a mathematical sense. I don't read something like this on other mathematical abstract areas as topology or measure theory ($\rightarrow$ forget this if you want, these are my REAL thoughts, maybe not good to express publicly, and I get angry when I dislike something, sorry, just don't read if you don't want to know my REAL opinions that, of course, are not "correct" in any political sense).

I will appreciate any enlightenment about this.

Comment: I don't know the reason for the term "over", but it is used to indicate the field from which the scalars for the scalar multiplication are chosen. In a similar vein, if one talks about the finite dimensional space $F^n$, then one considers this space as being "over $F$" in the sense that the $n$-tuples have entries that come from $F$.

Comment: A vector space is a $4$-tuple $(F,V,+,\cdot)$ where $F$ is a field, $V$ is a set, $+$ is a function from $V \times V$ to $V$, $\cdot$ is a function from $F \times V$ to $V$, and a certain list of axioms is satisfied.  With this definition, we never have to use the word "over" at all (and we also don't need to use the word "external").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a neat way to think about it, I think.

A vector space is a mathematical structure that can be built as follows.  We start with a set of objects that, first of all, you are able to add/subtract together (or, in the language of algebra, an abelian group).

As long as you are able to add things, it makes sense to define, at the very least, integer multiplication as a shorthand for addition.  So, for example, let's say that our vector space consists of the vectors "$x$" and "$y$".  We can say things like
$$
x + x = 2x\\
2x + 3x = (2+3)x = 5x\\
x - x = ``0"\\
2 \cdot (3x) = (2 \cdot 3)x = 6x\\
2x + 2y = 2(x + y) = (x+y) + (x + y)
$$
Now, remember, we haven't said anything about multiplying by scalars, we've just said that multiplying by integers already sort of makes sense anyway.

What we do in a vector space is extend that multiplication to include multiplication by elements in a *field*, and say that our multiplication should obey the same "common sense" rules (the axioms of a vector space).

So, if we take the field over which the space is defined to be $\Bbb Q$, it now makes sense to talk about, in addition to things like $2x$ and $3y$, things like $\frac 12 x$ and $\frac 23 y$.  The advantage of using a field is that scalar multiplication is nice in that (among other properties) it is now "invertible", unless you multiply by $0$.

So, for example, we can now say that $\frac 12 \cdot (2x) = (\frac 12 \cdot 2) x = x$.

In a sense, you can imagine that we've added a whole bunch of elements (such as $\frac 12 x + \frac 23 y$) to our original set by adding in the rule "you can also multiply by scalars".

Comment: Yes, this is my way to think about it. Is a bit confusing to me the order to define the things. And the words "over K" seems to put to much attention over the structure of vector space related more on K that it owns components. Just some perceptions. Thank a lot.

Comment: Some thing more: K need to be a field? It is not just to define as a set with different type of elements and follow the operations of V? Because calling K as field is like you will do operations closed on K that is not true.

Comment: Just because the terminology confused you, doesn't mean it's bad. If it doesn't seem deep from the definition, wait until you dive a bit further in.  In algebra (and perhaps in mathematics in general), depth comes from untangling complex relationships with simple structures like these.  Since you were wondering about the downvote, my guess is that it has a lot to do with the tone of your question, which sounds a bit like "I didn't understand this defintion, therefore it's bad".

Comment: If you drop the requirement that $K$ is a field, then what you end up with is called a "module" rather than a "vector space".  But vector spaces are necessarily defined "over" fields.

Comment: The definition seems very bad to me anyway. I dont have problems with more abstract definitions on topology or other areas of abstract algebra, just this. Any other definition for me is completely clear and well-defined... this seems to be not the better. I understand the meaning of vector space and properties, I understand clearly, but the definition seems to have (for me) a bit of poetry inside.

Comment: "*Because calling K as field is like you will do operations closed on K that is not true.*" I'm not quite sure what you mean here... could you elaborate?  I concede that, the way they are usually presented, the "axioms" seem contrived.  I don't agree with your misgivings on the word "over", which seems just as good as any.

Comment: It is just the words what make confuse the thing to me... if a read only the axioms on symbolic way (as in many other areas) it is completely clear. I dont see the need to K to be a field... you can define the operation of scalar multiplication taking elements of one set (a set K instead of a field) and use accordingly to the axioms for operations.

Comment: So, if we talk about *modules* rather than *vector spaces*, then $K$ does not necessarily need to be a field.  It does, however, need to be a *ring*, at the very least (that is, we need to be able to add and multiply scalars).  As it ends up, modules tend to be much more complicated than vector spaces.  For example, modules, don't necessarily have the (extremely useful) notion of "dimension" in the same way that vector spaces do.

Comment: What I think is that a ring or a field define internal operations, closed operations... what are not related to the scalar multiplication what is open relative to the field _K_ because scalar multiplication return vectors what arent on _K_. Maybe Im not understanding some relation here but if the return are vectors (that are not in _K_), why is the need to define K as a field then?Because operations of fields are closed.

Comment: I think I see what you're saying.  Yes, $K$ is used primarily as a way of taking one vector and giving you another.  For example, $\frac 23 (3,6,9) = (2,4,6)$: $\frac 23$ is a way of taking the vector $(3,6,9)$ to the vector $(2,4,6)$.  **However,** the manner in which $K$ acts on the vector space must be consistent with the multiplication within the field/ring.  So, if we wanted to figure out what $\frac 12$ of $(2,4,6)$ could possibly be, we would be forced to conclude $\frac 12 (2,4,6) = \frac 12 \frac 23 (3,6,9) = \frac 13 (3,6,9) = (1,2,3)$.

Comment: I also want to mention that the axioms are often presented this way because most people who first encounter vector spaces do not have any background in abstract algebra.  Given a background in abstract algebra, it is very easy to define a vector space and module in terms of abelian groups, rings, and group/ring actions, and these definitions are usually very neatly encapsulated.

Answer (score 2):

In this context, "over" just means that the scalars with which $V$ can be multiplied are coming from the field $K$.

It is not necessary for $K$ to be a subset of $V$.

Comment: So a vector space seems to be something like an application that can use two different type of arguments and return vectors. Anyway this type of definitions lack a lot of sense for me... must exist surely better ways to define a vector space.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "an application that can use two different type of arguments." Can you try to say that in another way?

Comment: A vector space is a thing that has an addition which acts like addition should intuitively behave, where you can scale elements of the vector space by scalars from the field, and such that the addition and scaling interact in a usual-kind-of-way.

Comment: what Im trying to say is that vector space is defined "over" _K_ but anyway it have his own set of vectors. For me seems that this "over K" included in the first lines of definition obscure a lot the meaning of vector space, because the K components are more related only to scalar multiplication. It will be more clear to me define just alone the vector space with composed of tuples and two operations, one that is related to a field K. Im trying to says that for me seems more clear order the information in other way, this seems to me so confusing.

Comment: If you find it convenient to visualize a vector space with tuples, then that is just fine. Since choosing a basis and writing everything explicitly in terms of tuples can be messy at times, people often find it more convenient to use the abstract definition and work without coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

A vector space involves two entities, $K$ a field and  a $V$. An operation involving two elements *both from* $V$ making it an abelian group.
An *inter-racial* (!) operation that involves an element of $K$ and an element of $V$ called scalar multiplication. This  should satisfy a plethora of conditions.

Don't get overworked with the choice of the word *over*. Mathematicians have committed far drastic sin like calling the group of integers $\mathbf{Z}$ a cyclic group where there is no periodicity. (*Monogenic*  would have been more appropriate).

Comment: -1 for the aside on cyclic groups (both for it being irrelevant and for it being just wrong, as the integers satisfy the definition of being cyclic).

Comment: I accept  the irrelevance here, and the downvoting it deserves. I would be happy to discuss in a thread where this can be the main theme? Any suggestions?

Comment: If you feel like discussing whether the integers is a cyclic group, you can join the main chat room (nothing much is happening there right now anyway).