# Formal specification of vector space.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, notation

The declaration of a field as a triplet $(\mathbb{K},\oplus,\odot)$ is canonical and in every book I've read, the definition of field is written using it. I can use this notation to describe any field in a strict and technical way. For example, this is how I can describe the finite field $\Bbb{Z}_2$:

$(\Bbb{Z}_2:=\{0,1\},\\\ \oplus:\Bbb{Z}_2^2\to\Bbb{Z}_2:=(x+y)\mod2,\\\
\odot:\Bbb{Z}_2^2\to\Bbb{Z}_2:=(x\cdot y)\mod2)$

I'm looking for a likewise technically strict way to describe a vector space over a field, since I've only found verbose specifications in common language (e.g., "a vector space $\mathbb{V}$ with operations $\oplus$ and $\odot$ over a field $\mathbb{k}$ with operations $+$ and $\cdot$").

There is any formal notation in which I can specify a vector space in few words (actually, in no words at all) as I do with fields?

Comment: I had [a similar problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/927917/cant-understand-some-definitions-of-abstract-algebra-can-you-help-me-please) some time ago. There are some definitions using the concept of [module](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Module_(mathematics)). The problem with the concept of vector space is that it was born from physics instead of mathematics.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're missing: if a vector space $V$ (over some specified field) has addition $\oplus$ and scalar multiplication $\odot$, then you can write it as a triple $(V,\oplus,\odot)$.  What more do you want?

Comment: @Masacroso if you understand the issue, could you clarify?  What exactly is "formal" about the field definition which is missing from the usual specifications of a vector space?

Comment: @eric-wofsey. Firstly, using the triplet $(\Bbb{V},\oplus,\odot)$ is ambiguous, since a field also have this notation. And secondly, this notation does not explicitly states which field this vector space is over, nor which are the two operations $+$ and $\cdot$ defined on this field.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom the main problem is lack of a formal definition in nearly all textbooks. In general the definition of vector space is not as formal as other algebraic structures. The reasons are history and costume. You can formalize the definition of vector space using concepts of abstract algebra but this is not the common way how a vector space is presented.

Comment: Can you say what the purpose of having such a "formal specification" is?  You seem to have some misunderstandings about how this notation is used (for instance, the notation you used to write the field $\mathbb{Z}_2$ is _not_ standard), so it is difficult to tell what you really want.

Comment: @Masacroso I don't know which textbooks you've read.  However, most textbooks that define a vector space define it as a set with operations $\oplus, \odot$ (or $+,\cdot$, whatever the notation happens to be) which satisfy the [8 axioms of a vector space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space#Definition).  That seems like a pretty formal definition to me.

Comment: @Seninha the $+,\cdot$ notation is [overloaded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_overloading), but not ambiguous.

Comment: @eric-wofsey. Indeed, the notation $\Bbb{Z}_2$ is not standard, and if I write this **alone**, it can be easily misunderstood. But in my example, I defined it, I assigned it to a specific set. In fact, I could name this set anything, since I used it not as a notation with represents a commonly used mathematical object, but as a name which I choose and assigned to something.

Comment: The purpose of having such a formal specification is just curiosity.
I searched for it once and I didn't found. Then I'm asking for it even whether it does not have any practical purpose.

Comment: @Seninha If you are interested in formal notations and formal specifications, why not look at *actual* machine-checked formal specification languages such as Coq, Agda, Z, MetaMath, Isabelle/HOL, etc.?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think one thing you're missing is that the term "vector space" doesn't really have a definition.  What has a definition is the term "vector space over $(K,+,\cdot)$", where $(K,+,\cdot)$ is some field.  So, if $(K,+,\cdot)$ is a field, then a **vector space over $(K,+,\cdot)$** is defined as a triple $(V,\oplus,\odot)$ where $V$ is a set, $\oplus:V\times V\to V$, $\odot:K\times V\to V$, and a certain long list of axioms are satified.  This is really a *separate* definition for every single field $(K,+,\cdot)$.

If you really want to have a definition of "vector space" without specifying the field beforehand (and this is *not* how people normally talk about vector spaces), you could define it as a tuple $(V,\oplus,\odot,K,+,\cdot)$ where $V$ and $K$ are sets, $\oplus:V\times V\to V$, $\odot:K\times V\to V$, $+:K\times K\to K$, $\cdot:K\times K\to K$, and an even longer list of axioms are satisfied.

Answer (score 7):

Formally, I don't see any additional challenge (of course, it gets more verbose, because you have more things to ask).

> Given a field $(\Bbb F,\oplus,\odot)$ a triple $(V,+,\cdot)$ is a $(\Bbb F,\oplus,\odot)$-*vector space* if and only if:
>
> 1. $(V,+)$ is an abelian group (= verbose subdefinition)
> 2. $\cdot:\Bbb F\times V\to V$ and $+:V\times V\to V$ satisfy:
>
>    - $\forall \alpha,\beta\in\Bbb K,\forall x\in V,\ (a\odot b)\cdot v=a\cdot(b\cdot v)$ or, if you want to be more formal, $\cdot(\odot(a,b),x)=\cdot(a,\cdot(b,x))$
>    - $\forall \alpha,\beta\in\Bbb K,\forall x\in V,\ (a\oplus b)\cdot x=(a\cdot x)+(b\cdot x)$ or, if you want to be more formal, $\cdot(\oplus(a,b),x)=+(\cdot(a,x),\cdot(b,x))$
>    - $\forall x\in V,\ 1_{\Bbb F}\cdot x=x$
>    - $\forall \alpha\in\Bbb K,\forall x,y\in V,\ \alpha\cdot(x+y)=(\alpha\cdot x)+(\beta\cdot y)$ or, if you want to be more formal, $\cdot(\alpha,+(x,y))=+(\cdot(\alpha,x),\cdot(\alpha,y))$

Typically, mathematicians (and anyone who has clear in mind what is what) swiftly adopt the big boys' notation $+:=\oplus$, $\text{nothing}:=\cdot:=\odot$, $0:=0_V$ and $0:= 0_{\Bbb F}$. This, basically because the aforementioned formal properties have the consequence of making such identifications harmless, as long as you have a way to distinguish vectors from scalars. This is acheived by noticing that, as long as multiplication by scalar acts on the left and you don't introduce a "dot product of two vectors", the only way to make sense of a "monomial" such as $abcd\in V$ is by assuming $a,b,c\in \Bbb F$ and $d\in V$, thus reading it $(a\odot b\odot c)\cdot d$. Similarly for $x(a+b)(c+d)=(x\odot(a\oplus b))\cdot (c+d)$